# Filtering out bad words in MUD Game

Tags: c++, validation, mud

In my C++ MUD game i want to be able to eliminate the player from being able to enter curse words.  You all know what they are, no need for examples.  So i tried something like this:

```
vector<string> vulger = { "You know what goes in here");

void Player::SendString(const std::string& p_string)
    {
for (vector<string>::iterator it = vulger.begin(); it != vulger.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (!p_string.compare(*it) || !p_string.find(*it))
        {
            //Testing what words are been neglected by the if statement.
            //cout << *it;
                Conn()->Protocol().SendString(*Conn(), p_string + newline);
        }
    }

    }
```

But all this does is loop through strings that are sent to the network.  Including announcments.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong or suggest anything maybe ?

Comment: Your parameter is named `p_string`, but you're using `!p_name` inside your loop. What is `p_name`?

Comment: Sorry they are just typos i will edit them now.

Comment: Don't retype code here. It's impossible to spot problems in your code if it's not your actual code. Retyping can hide the problem (or introduce new ones, as happened here). Copy and paste instead.

Comment: Be careful so you don't block discussions about Joe Cocker.

Comment: Your code is written to loop through strings that are sent to the network. What else do you expect it to do?

Comment: @KenWhite  I want a message to be sent to the network when there is an offensive word used.  Then i will create a removeWord function to handle this.

Comment: Anything that is sent to the network is being marked as offensive there must be a problem with the compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `||` in your `if` statement to `&&`:

```
    void Player::SendString(const std::string& p_string)
    {
      for (vector<string>::iterator it = vulger.begin(); it != vulger.end(); ++it)
      {
#if 0
// Original:
        if (!p_name.compare(*it) && !p_name.find(*it))
        {
          Conn()->Protocol().SendString(*Conn(), p_string + newline);
        }
        else
        {
          cout << "Vulgar word found: " << *it << "\n";
        }
#else
// Edit 1:  Changed ordering.
        if ((p_name == *it) || (p_name.find(*it) != std::string::npos))
        {
          cout << "Vulgar word found: " << *it << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
          Conn()->Protocol().SendString(*Conn(), p_string + newline);
        }
#endif

      }
    }
```

Comment: From testing this ive found that the whole list is printing out rather than just the vulger word when it is entered.

Comment: See my changes, "Edit 1".  I've simplified the logic to *if word is vulgar, print, else send word*.

Comment: Using the updated version, everything sent to the network is being looped as many times as there is contents in the vector.

Comment: However it is now picking up when the vulgur word is sent to the network.

Comment: You need to remove the vulgar word from the `p_string` variable before sending `p_string` to the network.  The `if` statement only *identifies* the vulgar word, it doesn't remove it from the `p_string`, so the vulgar word will still be sent to the network.

Comment: Do you think that  this is also causing the problem with the looping ?

Comment: whats the best low cost way to remove from the middle of a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the return value of `std::string::find` as a bool, when, in actuality, it returns an offset into the string with a special magic value of `npos` if it's not found.

```
if (my_string.find("foo") == std::npos) {
   // foo is NOT in my_string
} else {
   // foo is in my_string
}
```